# How To do update/edit on selenium script got in JAR file format from other location

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have a Runnable JAR file of selenium script forwarded from other location, now I want to use that same script for my project with some minor updates. How to do that? Can we open that in Eclipse and do updates/Edits on JAR File script?

Comment: If you want to make modifications - you need the sources. Does the JAR file contain sources and do you also have a build script?

Comment: @DakshinamurthyKarra I have only JAR Files

Answer (score 1):

Jar file contains java classes - the files which are converted from the source code to the bytecode. You cannot easily change that. There is a way to decompile classes to the source. However:

- That might not help you even if you're a skilled developer if a bytecode was handled by an obfuscator.
- Decompilation requires quite a big degree of understanding of what is happening and why. If you are ready to dive deep into that, check [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272535/how-do-i-decompile-java-class-files).